# How to disable satellite & terrain option on ng-map?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ng-map

I want to disable satellite & terrain option on the top left of ng-map.

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried mapTypeControl: false & streetViewControl: false when you configure your map instance?

Comment: Thanks, Mokky. Your answer is what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using the property map-type-control="false" or disable-default-u-i="true" to disable all properties if you want.